# i'm having these error: subscripts must be either integers 1 to (2^31)-1 or logicals

Tags: matlab, octave

I'm starting to program and choose octave couse it's the free "version" of matlab, the program they use here at my university.
So, these problem apears when i try to run my code:

> ***error: I(0): subscripts must be either integers 1 to (2^31)-1 or logicals***

and I don't know why, because when I put R in place of **RR**, the code works.
I thought that maybe the problem was that **R-Rn** isn't reeeally equal 0, but something close to it, ans thus the problem, but after doing some tests with simple numbers, I found out that it was actually 0, but maybe it's diferent for matrixes.
Please help.
oh, and don't pay attention to the notes, i'm from brazil.

```
clear          
tic                                       %inicio da cronometragem      
f = @(x) 16*x.^6 + 8*x -6;                %definir função      
df = @(x) 96*x.^5 + 8;                    %definir derivada da função  
tol = 10E-4;                              %define a tolerancia  
xmin = -5;                                %menor valor para X  
xmax = 5;                                 %maior valor para X  
ymin = -5;                                %menor valor para Y  
ymax = 5;                                 %maior valor para Y  
npx = 8;                                  %número de pontos do eixo X  
npy = 8;                                  %número de pontos do eixo Y
dx = (xmax-xmin)/npx;                     %calculo da distância entre os 
pontos do eixo X  
dy = (ymax-ymin)/npy;                     %calculo da distância entre os 
pontos do eixo Y  
A = zeros(npy+1, npx+1);                  %define matriz cheia de 0, do 
tamanho definido por npx e npy  
x = xmin:dx:xmax;                         %define tamanho e distancia entre os pontos de uma linha      
y= ymin:dy:ymax;                          %define tamanho e distancia entre os pontos de uma coluna      
A = x+i*y';                               %preenche a matriz A com os valores desta multiplicação  
[m n] = size(A);                          %define m e n como o tamanho da linha e coluna, respectivamente, da matriz A  
I = zeros(m,n);                           %cria outra matriz, I, de mesmo tamanho de A, mas cheia de 0  
i = 0;                                    %numero de interações definido como 0  
R = I;  
for kk = 1:50                         %define numero de interações do metodo de newton   
  An = A-f(A)./df(A);                 %método de newton  
  i = i + 1;                          %aumentar o numero de interação a cada vez que repete  
  Rn = R  
  R = abs((An - A)) < tol             %cria uma matriz R com 1 ou 0 se a posição alcançou a tolerancia ou não  
  RR = R - Rn  
  I(RR) = i                           %preenche a matriz I com o numero de interação de cada posição da matriz A  
  A = An;                             %iguala A com An para que o metodo de newton possa continuar  
  end  

imagesc(I)                                %forma o fractal  
toc                                       %para o cronômetro
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for R because R is a logical array - indexing with a logical array accepts 0 as a value because 0 in logical array indexing means 'don't apply to this element'.

When you subtract your array Rn, RR becomes an array of doubles. Indexing this way cannot accept 0 as there is no 0th element.

You need to convert RR to a logical array (the function is 'logical' in MATLAB) for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

When I run the code I get that RR is all zeros. In MATLAB indexes start at 1 (so zero is an invalid index). Try changing `RR = R - Rn` to `RR = R - Rn + 1`. This at least lets the code run and produce an image (although I'm not sure if the image is correct).

Comment: In octave, it works just fine, and the proof is that if I  put R over RR, it works, even if R is also all zeros at first.